# How to upload files to S3 using Signature v4

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I'm trying this for couple of days now but getting stuck at signature calculation. for the background, I've an EC2 instance role assign to the instance and also need to use MKS SSE (Server Side encryption) to store data in S3.

So, this is the script I'm using now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -E
export TERM=xterm
#    
s3_region='eu-west-1'
s3_bucket='my-s3-file-bucket'
#
bkup_optn='hourly'
data_type='application/octet-stream'
bkup_path="/tmp/backups/${bkup_optn}"
bkup_file="$( ls -t ${bkup_path}|head -n1 )"
timestamp="$( LC_ALL=C date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )"
#
appHost="$( hostname -f )"
thisApp="$( facter -p my_role )"
thisEnv="$( facter -p my_environment )"
upldUri="${thisEnv}/${appHost}/${bkup_optn}/${bkup_file}"

# This doesn't work on OS X
iso_timestamp=$(date -ud "${timestamp}" "+%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
date_scope=$(date -ud "${timestamp}" "+%Y%m%d")
date_header=$(date -ud "${timestamp}" "+%a, %d %h %Y %T %Z")

## AWS instance role
awsMetaUri='http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/'
awsInstRole=$( curl -s ${awsMetaUri} )
awsAccessKey=$( curl -s ${awsMetaUri}${awsInstRole}|awk -F'"' '/AccessKeyId/ {print $4}' )
awsSecretKey=$( curl -s ${awsMetaUri}${awsInstRole}|grep SecretAccessKey|cut -d':' -f2|sed 's/[^0-9A-Za-z/+=]*//g' )
awsSecuToken=$( curl -s ${awsMetaUri}${awsInstRole}|sed -n '/Token/{p;}'|cut -f4 -d'"' )
signedHeader='date;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-server-side-encryption;x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id'
echo -e "awsInstRole  => ${awsInstRole}\nawsAccessKey => ${awsAccessKey}\nawsSecretKey => ${awsSecretKey}"

payload_hash()
{
  local output=$(shasum -ba 256 "${bkup_path}/${bkup_file}")
  echo "${output%% *}"
}

canonical_request()
{
  echo "PUT"
  echo "/${upldUri}"
  echo ""
  echo "date:${date_header}"
  echo "host:${s3_bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  echo "x-amz-security-token:${awsSecuToken}"
  echo "x-amz-content-sha256:$(payload_hash)"
  echo "x-amz-server-side-encryption:aws:kms"
  echo "x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id:arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx111:key/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx1432"
  echo "x-amz-date:${iso_timestamp}"
  echo ""
  echo "${signedHeader}"
  printf "$(payload_hash)"
}

canonical_request_hash() 
{
  local output=$(canonical_request | shasum -a 256)
  echo "${output%% *}"
}

string_to_sign()
{
  echo "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"
  echo "${iso_timestamp}"
  echo "${date_scope}/${s3_region}/s3/aws4_request"
  echo "x-amz-security-token:${awsSecuToken}"
  echo "x-amz-server-side-encryption:aws:kms"
  echo "x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id:arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx111:key/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx1432"
  printf "$(canonical_request_hash)"
}

signature_key()
{
  local secret=$(printf "AWS4${awsSecretKey}" | hex_key)
  local date_key=$(printf ${date_scope} | hmac_sha256 "${secret}" | hex_key)
  local region_key=$(printf ${s3_region} | hmac_sha256 "${date_key}" | hex_key)
  local service_key=$(printf "s3" | hmac_sha256 "${region_key}" | hex_key)
  printf "aws4_request" | hmac_sha256 "${service_key}" | hex_key
}

hex_key() {
  xxd -p -c 256
}

hmac_sha256() {
  local hexkey=$1
  openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:${hexkey}
}

signature() {
  string_to_sign | hmac_sha256 $(signature_key) | hex_key | sed "s/^.* //"
}

curl \
  -T "${bkup_path}/${bkup_file}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=${awsAccessKey}/${date_scope}/${s3_region}/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=${signedHeader},Signature=$(signature)" \
  -H "Date: ${date_header}" \
  -H "x-amz-date: ${iso_timestamp}" \
  -H "x-amz-security-token:${awsSecuToken}" \
  -H "x-amz-content-sha256: $(payload_hash)" \
  -H "x-amz-server-side-encryption:aws:kms" \
  -H "x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id:arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx111:key/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx1432" \
  "https://${s3_bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${upldUri}"
```

It was written following this doc: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html and parts from a sample script in Github, which I forgot to bookmark. After the initial bumpy ride, now I'm keep getting this error:

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
```

I went through several AWS docs but I cannot figure out why. Anyone can help me out here please?

-San

Comment: The error message gives you the exact bytes of the string to sign.  Examine the one you are generating, perhaps using `hexdump -C`, to confirm whether it is precisely identical.

Comment: You are using KMS. But no KMS id. Read the last section here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingKMSEncryption.html

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll report back soon if that works.

Comment: okay, modified the code to add `x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id` (updated the OP) but still getting the same sig not matching error. Is my `canonical_request_hash()` and `string_to_sign()` look okay? Any other thought(s)?

Comment: According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html the canonical headers (as part of the canonical request) should be in alphabetical order.

Comment: @MacUsers Did you get this working? Would be great to know. Thanks!